# sending SMS in IOS Custome SMS Composer

Tags: iphone, ios, sms

I am looking for sending SMS through my iPhone app.
There is a condition , i am not using the default composer of iPhone, i have designed my own design.
There is a text box and send button, so sms should go to the selected respective phone no of phone book.

I have done that with default compose, but i want to go with customize sms composer.

Please help in this case.

Thanks,
Gopal

Answer (score 4):

If you want to use iOS' built-in SMS API, I'm afraid you must also use the built-in message composer (it's part of the package deal). That said, you could always use a [third-party SMS gateway](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2177308/sending-an-sms-myself), and rather than send the SMS directly from the phone, you could send it via HTTP to the gateway.